# scroll page when scroll on div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div, when I scroll on div, page should scroll, how can I achieve this?
Div has z-index higher than other page elements, it's on top of all page elements

Using javascript or jQuery, anything?

Edit: DIV is the top most element, other elements have lower z-index. Now top DIV is longer than viewport, so I need to scroll

Comment: could you make it more clear. If you are scrolling should not you page also be scrolling?

Comment: What behavior are you currently getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook up the `.Scroll()` event on the div using jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/. Then each time the callback is called I belive you can set the `scrollTop` position to something that corresponds to a similar position to the div.

```
$(function() {
    $('#yourDiv').scroll(function() {
        $(window).scrollTop($(window).height() * $(this).scrollTop() / $(this).height());
    });
});
```

This was just a rough guess. But the idea is to find how far down the `div` has scrolled and scroll the window down the same percentage.

Finally the `div` will need to be `position: absolute;` I believe.

Comment: @I-M-JM: I didn't test it, i'm just giving you an example. What have you tried? Try mocking up an example on a website like http://jsfiddle.net and we'll be more inclined to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, attach an event listener on the div for scroll.
In the event handler, change the document.scrollTo accordingly.
Make sure the div is a floating dom element.